# Is there any other way to output the data only when the program reaches the end of program?

Tags: c++, c

```
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("output:%d\n",n);
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("output:%d\n",n);
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("output:%d\n",n);
```

The instruction `printf` outputs the number right after executing, is there any other way to output the data only when the program reaches the end of program?

I want:

```
3
4
5
output:3
output:4
output:5
```

not:

```
3
output:3
4
output:4
5
output:5
```

Comment: You could use recursion

Comment: No, there is no predefined function to add elements to a raw array, because it's just one statement in the first place.

Comment: `printf` uses a buffer by default, and will print out a bunch of characters at a time when it gets a `'\n'` character, so you don't need to worry about that. BTW C and C++ are different languages, don't tag them both

Comment: what, when and where do you want to print, it's up to you.

Comment: There are two separate issues here. First (as @LưuVĩnhPhúc says), `printf()` output is normally line buffered if the output device is an interactive device — aka terminal — so operations like `printf("%d", tmp*10)` normally wouldn't produce output until either the buffer fills or a newline is generated. Second, counteracting that tendency not to print data too soon, if the input and output are interactive devices, then `scanf()` will often flush standard output so any pending output (e.g. a prompt such as `printf("Next: ")`) will appear before the input is read. You're probably seeing this.

Comment: I regarded your now-deleted question [SO 40816188](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40816188/) as different from this, though they're closely related.  To do what you want, you'll need to save the output in a string or array of strings, and arrange to print the string(s) when you want to trigger it.  You may find `snprintf()` helpful; if your systems support them, the `asprintf()` family of functions can be useful too.  I have a pair of files (`memfmt.c`, `memfmt.h`) that implement a usable facility for that behaviour — but it is close to 350 lines of code including comments and test code.

Comment: why don't just declare 3 variables, `scanf` them then print them all at the end?

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion to accomplish this.

```
int main(){    
    int n=2;
    foo(n);
}
void foo(int n){
    int tmp;
    if(!n){
        return;
    }else{
        scanf("%d",&tmp);
        foo(n--);
        printf("%d",tmp);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a relatively recent POSIX system (2008 POSIX spec), you can use `open_memstream` to open a `FILE` that spools the text to memory, where you can later get at in and actually print it:

```
char *buffer = 0;
size_t buffer_len;
FILE *fp = open_memstream(&buffer, &buffer_len);
while(scanf("%d",&tmp) == 1) {
    fprintf(fp, "%d",tmp*10);
}
// write the whole buffer now
fwrite(buffer, 1, buffer_len, stdout);
// and free it
free(buffer);
```

In C++, you would use a `std::stringstream` in much the same way, though you use `<<` to write to it, rather than `fprintf`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a function in the standard library. I'd suggest pushing values onto a `std::vector<int>` and then looping through that afterwards:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
...
numbers.push_back(tmp);
...
for (int n : numbers)
    printf("%d\n", n);
```

Answer (score 0):

I speculate you want to do this because your output device(printf) is too slow than your input device(scanf). This can happen in a lot of embedded devices.

There is no library function that can batch scan your data and print them later after some trigger as you mentioned in description.

I would recommend you to allocate some memory block before looping to scan data. And when you complete scanning, print them using loop.

Sudo code:

```
data = malloc(size)

loop(size)
{
    *data = scanf();
    data++;
{
loop(size)
{
    printf(data++)
}
```